# Symfony 2 - Top menu not appearing in Sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Top menu not appearing in my Sonata admin. The menus are only appearing in the Dashboard.

I followed the following tutorial and created the backend for blog feature:
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/introduction.html

I also tried configuring app/config/config.yml like as below

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            Blog:
```

But the expected result (i.e. the top menu) is not obtained.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.2, it's a matter of security. Once you've configured it [as the docs says](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html), the menu will display properly.

**UPDATE:** Also, the user must have the role `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN`, according to [the 2012-06-05 entry on the changelog](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2012-06-05).

If you want to test it without doing that, you can [set a new layout template](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html) based on this file: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig, but commenting some lines related to the menu drawing in the block `sonata_top_bar_nav`, like this:

```
{% block sonata_top_bar_nav %}
  {#% if app.security.token and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') %#}
    {% for group in admin_pool.dashboardgroups %}
      {% set display = (group.roles is empty or is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') ) %}
        {% for role in group.roles if not display %}
          {% set display = is_granted(role) %}
        {% endfor %}

        {# Do not display the group label if no item in group is available #}
        {% set item_count = 0 %}
        {% if display %}
          {% for admin in group.items if item_count == 0 %}
            {% if admin.hasroute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
              {% set item_count = item_count+1 %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {#% if display and (item_count > 0) %#}
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ group.label|trans({}, group.label_catalogue) }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for admin in group.items %}
              {#% if admin.hasroute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %#}
                <li><a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list')}}">{{ admin.label|trans({}, admin.translationdomain) }}</a></li>
              {#% endif %#}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
        {# % endif %#}
      {% endfor %}
    {#% endif %#}
  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `SONATA_ROLE_ADMIN` to show the menu

You can set it in `security.yml` for ROLE_ADMIN to include it

```
security:
    ...
    role_hierarchy:
        ...
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the bundle `yml` file in the `config.yml` file.

example :

```
imports:
    - { resource: @yourBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

Your `admin.yml` looks like this :

```
# website/yourBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
services:
    sonata.admin.your:
        class: website\yourBundle\Admin\yourAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Contact Management" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - website\yourBundle\Entity\your
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [yourBundle]]
```

Comment: This I am already giving in the config.yml like the following:
services:
   tutorial.blog.admin.post:
      class: Tutorial\BlogBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Blog, label: Post }
      arguments: [null, Tutorial\BlogBundle\Entity\Post, TutorialBlogBundle:PostAdmin]